# Parsing enum flags from comma-separated list or integer

Tags: c#, xml, enums, enum-flags, bitflags

I have an XML that contains several flags, some of them are unsigned 32-bit integers and others are unsigned 64-bit integers. Some of them are written in a comma-separated list and others are in hex style.

See this example:

```xml
<Color>Blue,Red</Color>
<Color>0xC</Color>
```

As I don't want to write a method to parse each enum, I decided to use a generic method. But Visual Studio won't let me build the solution. Here's my method:

```cs
public static T ParseFlags<T>(string value) where T : struct
{
    T result = (T)((object)0);
    string[] array;
    // Remove white spaces and delimit string if it is comma-separated
    if (ParseDelimitedString(value, ',', out array))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            T flag = (T)((object)0);
            // Check if value is member of enumeration
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(array[i], out flag))
            {
                result |= (T)((object)flag);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))))
        {
            // Remove hex characters and parse node's inner text
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                result = (T)((object)ParseUint(value));
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                result = (T)((object)ParseUlong(value));
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The error message I get is:

> Error 1   Operator '|=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and
>   'T'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't this `result |= (T)((object)flag);` be this instead `result = (T)((object)flag);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing a lot of work that can be done for you. For example, if your `enum` is declared with the `FlagsAttribute` then `Enum.Parse` will parse comma separated values for you.

```
public static T ParseFlags<T>(string value) where T : struct
{
    T result;
    ulong temp;
    if (Enum.TryParse(value, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    string hexNum = value.StartsWith("0x") ? value.Substring(2) : value;
    if (ulong.TryParse(hexNum, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out temp))
    {
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), temp);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("value could not be parsed");
}
```

I tested this with various Flags enum types with `short`, `int`, and `ulong` backing values.

Comment: I didn't know it could handle comma-separated values, thank you. This seems to be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what type of enum you're parsing:

```
    [Fact]
    public void when_parsing_options_then_can_combine_flags()
    {
        var values = "Singleline | Compiled";

        var options = values.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(value => (RegexOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegexOptions), value))
            .Aggregate(RegexOptions.None, (current, value) => current |= value);

        Assert.Equal(RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static T ParseFlags<T>(string value) where T : struct
{
    long result = 0L;
    string[] array;
    // Remove white spaces and delimit string if it is comma-separated
    if (ParseDelimitedString(value, ',', out array))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            T flag = default(T);
            // Check if value is member of enumeration
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(array[i], out flag))
            {
                result |= (long)flag;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))))
        {
            // Remove hex characters and parse node's inner text
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                result = ParseUint(value);
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                result = ParseUlong(value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return (T)((object)result);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"|=" usage in that snippet makes me think you meant to use the Enum as bitset not just any old Enum.  If this is true, you should make a small change - declare the local "result" as int and adjust the casts appropriately, your return statement should then be "return (T)(object)result;".  That line in question with "|" would look like: "result |= (int)(object)flag;".  Perhaps, there is a better answer but, note that [enums are integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) and your scenario of bitset are covered well enough with this solution unless there are situations I missed or you did not state.